# Why mpsc::Sender#send and mpsc::Receiver#recv is not marked as mut?

Tags: rust

Why the `Sender::send`/`Receiver::recv` methods take `&self` instead of `&mut self`? They are wrapping their internal state using `UnsafeCell` but I don't get why.

Comment: Non-mut reference in Rust means "safe to share" it doesn't imply that underlying data structures won't change. (Though such a guarantee is provided by the primitive types, when interior mutability is not used.) In this case this is presumably done so the reference to a channel is easier to share among multiple data structure in the thread (or behind an `Arc` where it's convenient to avoid a namspace). They use atomics internally anyway, so they suffer no performance loss by allowing access through shared reference.

Comment: Good point, it is also consistent with similar data types, like Atomic types, etc. But when we make it non-mut then it also means that it can be aliased, is that safe?

Comment: `UnsafeCell` makes aliasing safe (still requiring `unsafe` because you need to take care of synchronization).

Comment: But at least in the case of *Receiver* class, shouldn't it be *mut* in order to call `recv`? Anyways it is not safe to share `recv` without a lock or something.

Comment: Awwww it is safe to share `recv` in a single thread. I think I have my answer.

Comment: Yes, for `Receiver::recv()` taking `&self` makes it easier to share inside a thread. I guess `Sender::send()` could take `&mut self` since you can clone the sender as you wish anyway. But since the implementation is based on sharing anyway (required to support cloning), I guess it was decided that taking `&self` makes life a bit easier for API users without compromising the implementation.

Comment: The cool thing is, both of them are `!Sync` so they can not be shared between threads directly (and only `Sender` has a proper `clone` method). So the multi threaded scenario is not possible.

Comment: @AmirHossein When you say "should not take self as mut?" you mean "should not take &mut self instead of &self? "

Comment: Yes @Jerboas86, I mean exactly that.